# Seaborn boxplot - spaces beetween plots and categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

got problem with figure. I made seaborn boxplot for days and hours (1h stamp).

I also get median value on boxes.

My problem is that it is unreadable cause mediana text. I would like to change spaces beetween data sets for hours but cant find calling for it. Anyone can help?

Look at attached pic: i want change space between 2021&2022 and between hours[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PjAf.jpg)

Code: https://Control.com/7ae270bf

I cant find seaborn boxplot parameter to change spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `width` argument in the `sns.boxplot()` function to change the space between boxplots/hours. Next you can increase the ax width (by setting `figsize` when you create the axes). Together this will create more space between boxplots.

Comment: That works, thank you so much but got another question. If i change width boxes goes out of plot border. How to prevent it, "Margin"?

Comment: If I understand this right; it's best to adjust the visible window of the plot by setting the ax limits. 
`ax.set_xlim([x_min, x_max])`, where `x_min` and `x_max` are two scalars indicating the start and end of the visible part of the x-axis. (And same for y-axis if needed).